# How to adjust the size of the input component?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table, user-experience

Here is the UI prototype I am trying to implement 
[image]

Here is what I currently have : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54cwezo6/9/)  and what my layout looks like currently 
[image]

I am trying to adjust the size of the input component so that it matches the height in the UI/the search icon.

Here is the HTML code for the input component 
(I set [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) to 3 so that the input will span from "Contact Us"  to the American flag.)

```
<td colspan="3"><input class="help_header" type="text" /></td>
```

And the CSS code to style it

```
input {
    background-color:white;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align:bottom;   
}
```

Does anyone know how to adjust the height of the input component in this case? I tried setting the height attribute to 1px but that didn't do anything. I also tried vertical-aligning it with the bottom of the search icon but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding from `.help-header` is giving the `<input>` height some trouble.

Removing the padding from the `input` did the trick, by modifying the selector to `.help_header:not(input)`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzb123hv/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use font-size and line-height attrs. Or set overflow: hidden, so you can use height attribute. There is good article on this subject http://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/